# Why set bg-container's position to absolute?

Tags: css

[position: absolute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZmml.png)

[delete position property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ra6q.png)

I just tested this page in chrome, I am confused about the position property used in the bg-container, but when I delete this property, the background image(coke) disappear, what's problem, I thought position  property is not related to background image.
the code looks like below

```
 .bg-container {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-image: url('../../../../Content/themes/segmentedexecution/images/home-bg.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I just added the code.

Answer (score 0):

No, `position: absolute` has no effect on the background image, but it can affect the location of the element with the background.

An element which is positioned absolute is taken out of the page flow. Therefore it can be below/on top of other elements, which I believe is what is happening in your example. In order for `bg-container` to be in the same space as the other elements on the page, it is positioned absolute. When you remove `position: absolute`, it is part of the page flow and gets wrapped below the stuff on the page. Combined with `overflow: hidden` on its parent element, it would seem to disappear.

Comment: Hi, I think the cause might be that the div.bg-container could not get its height, so the background image wont appear.(I have three divs in the body and they all have position: absolute; so the body's height becomes 0px), I delete bg-container's positon: absolute; property and set body a fixed width and height, the bg-container 's background image appear normally, so my question is, why add position:absolute works?(height: 100% when the body's height is 0 but the background image still show)